# Bind URL to components rendered by the state

Tags: reactjs, routes

I am rendering two components inside a component that is named `Subscribe`.
This two components are `SubscribeStep1`, `SubscribeStep2`, and `SubscribeStep3`. 
This components are rendered by the state triggered by click events.

```
<TabContent activeTab={step}>
          {step === 1 ? (
            <TabPane tabId={1}>
              <SubscribeStep1
                nextStep={this.nextStep}
                updateProp={this.updateProp}
              />
            </TabPane>
          ) : (
            ''
          )}
          {step === 2 ? (
            <TabPane tabId={2}>
              <SubscribeStep2
                previousStep={this.previousStep}
                nextStep={this.nextStep}
                updateProp={this.updateProp}
              />
            </TabPane>
          ) : (
            ''
          )}
</TabContent>
```

What I need is to change the URL when the user access to this sub-components.
In that way, if he want, he can go back and go forward using the navigator buttons of the browser.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to study and try
[React Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start)

your task will be much easier.

You can change the url thanks to NavLiks or with history.push('your url') inside subcomponents.

```js
<TabContent>
  <Switch>
    <Route render={()=>(
      <TabPane tabId={1}>
        <SubscribeStep1
          nextStep={this.nextStep}
          updateProp={this.updateProp}
        />
      </TabPane>
    )} />
    
    <Route render={()=>(
      <TabPane tabId={2}>
        <SubscribeStep2
          nextStep={this.nextStep}
          updateProp={this.updateProp}
        />
      </TabPane>
    )} />
 
  </Switch>
 </TabContent>
```

your component will become something like this!

Comment: Thanks a lot. But where to put the URL in that example? Maybe adding the attribute path of the Route component? Is also necessary to add the URL in the chindren component?

Comment: Inside SubscribeStep components you can add <NavLinks to={'your url'} /> or a <Button onClick={() => { history.push('your url') } />